# Java - I am overlooking something and need help. What am I missing here

Tags: java

I am writing a very simple Java program, but pulling the wrong info on run. I know it is something small, but need a new set of eyes. Please take a look and thank you in advance.

I have searched everywhere and this is one of my last steps.

```
package example;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CustomersChange {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a Scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    final double MONEY = 100;

    // Receive the amount
    System.out.print("Enter the amount of your purchase in whole dollars, for example 96. "
            + "You have $100 to spend: ");
    double amount = input.nextDouble();

    int changeLeft = (int)(amount * 100);

    // Find the number of twenties left
    int numberOfTwenties = changeLeft / 2000;
    changeLeft = changeLeft % 2000;

    // Find the number of tens left
    int numberOfTens = changeLeft / 1000;
    changeLeft = changeLeft % 1000;

    // Find the number of fives left
    int numberOfFives = changeLeft / 500;
    changeLeft = changeLeft % 500;

    // Find the number of ones in the left
    int numberOfDollars = changeLeft / 100;
    changeLeft = changeLeft % 100;

    // Display results
    System.out.println("Your change is " + (MONEY - amount) + " dollars.");
    System.out.println("Your change of " + (MONEY - amount) + " dollars has:");     
    System.out.println("    " + numberOfTwenties + " twenties ");
    System.out.println("    " + numberOfTens + " tens");
    System.out.println("    " + numberOfFives + " fives");
    System.out.println("    " + numberOfDollars + " dollars");

  }

}
```

Comment: What is the exact question ?

Comment: Everything ids working except I am pulling the user input instead of getting the correct change. If you can run you will see exactly what I mean. Thanks

Comment: How can I fix my code so my result is the change and not the user input?

Comment: In the future (or now) you will want to write better questions here as this will likely help folks better understand your problem, and this will gain you better answers. So don't use non-helpful titles like "what am I missing ..." as that tells us absolutely *nothing* about your actual problem. Instead summarize the actual problem in a sentence and use that. Also spend more time describing your code, what you want it to do, what it's not doing that it should be doing, what it is doing that it shouldn't be... a little effort goes a long way.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change
`int changeLeft = (int)(amount * 100);`

to
 `int changeLeft = (int)(MONEY - amount)*100;`

Comment: Thank you!! I knew it was something silly. I really appreciate it.